# Hibernate annotations with DataSource en sessionFactory in Spring project

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I'm trying to use Hibernate's annotation with a dataSource in my web Application with Spring but I've an error "NoSuchBeanDefinitionException" and I don't know why. From my point of view all is correct... If somebody can help me to resolve it it's very good for me :)

Here it's my root-context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd 
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd 
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd 
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd 
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee 
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.2.xsd"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" 
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" 
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans">

<context:component-scan base-package="fot.manager.service, fot.manager.dao" />

<context:annotation-config />

<!-- To use transactions -->
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

<!-- DataSource -->
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/f1_tycoon" />
    <property name="username" value="root" />
    <property name="password" value="" />
</bean>

<!-- Hibernate -->
<bean id="sessionFactory" name="connectionDB"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="myDataSource" />
    <property name="annotatedClasses">
        <list>
            <value>fot.manager.model.Bannissement</value>
            <value>fot.manager.model.CategorieForum</value>
            <value>fot.manager.model.CategorieNews</value>
            <value>fot.manager.model.Commentaire</value>
            <value>fot.manager.model.MessageForum</value>
            <value>fot.manager.model.News</value>
            <value>fot.manager.model.Pilote</value>
            <value>fot.manager.model.Rang</value>
            <value>fot.manager.model.SectionForum</value>
            <value>fot.manager.model.Signalement</value>
            <value>fot.manager.model.SujetForum</value>
            <value>fot.manager.model.Utilisateur</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <value> 
            hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
            hibernate.show_sql=true 
            hibernate.format_sql=true
        </value>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>
```

Web.xml :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
            xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
            xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
            xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>fot.manager</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>connexion.html</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

  <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/classes/root-context.xml</param-value>
  </context-param>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <!-- Ajax servlet -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>ajax</servlet-name>
            <servlet-class>
                org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
            </servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

  <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>ajax</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/ajax/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping> 
</web-app>
```

And the stacktrace :

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [fot.manager.service.NewsService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:986)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:856)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:768)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:486)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:285)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1122)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:461)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:626)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:651)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:599)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:665)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:518)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:459)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1284)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1197)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1087)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5493)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.reload(StandardContext.java:3988)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappLoader.backgroundProcess(WebappLoader.java:425)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.backgroundProcess(ContainerBase.java:1345)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1530)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1540)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1540)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.run(ContainerBase.java:1519)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I've also an other error stacktrace for a Java file:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jqGridController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private fot.manager.service.NewsService fot.manager.ajax.jqGridController.newsService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [fot.manager.service.NewsService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:288)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1122)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:461)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:626)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:651)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:599)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:665)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:518)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:459)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1284)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1197)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1087)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5493)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.reload(StandardContext.java:3988)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappLoader.backgroundProcess(WebappLoader.java:425)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.backgroundProcess(ContainerBase.java:1345)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1530)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1540)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1540)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.run(ContainerBase.java:1519)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private fot.manager.service.NewsService fot.manager.ajax.jqGridController.newsService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [fot.manager.service.NewsService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:514)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:285)
    ... 31 more
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [fot.manager.service.NewsService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:986)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:856)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:768)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:486)
        ... 33 more
```

And the Java file :

```
package fot.manager.ajax;

import java.util.Collection;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

import fot.manager.model.News;
import fot.manager.service.NewsService;

@Controller

@RequestMapping("/ajax")

public class jqGridController {

    @Autowired
    private NewsService newsService;

    // Contrôleur pour afficher les news
    @RequestMapping("/getNews")
    @ResponseBody
    public Collection<News> getNews(){
        Collection<News> listNews = newsService.getAllNews();

        for (News news : listNews){
            System.out.println(news.getAuteur().getPseudo());
        }

        return listNews;
    }
}
```

My NewsService class Implement :

```
    package fot.manager.service.impl;

import java.util.Collection;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import fot.manager.dao.NewsDao;
import fot.manager.model.News;
import fot.manager.service.NewsService;

@Service("newsService")
@Transactional
public class NewsServiceImpl implements NewsService {

    @Autowired
    private NewsDao newsDao;

    @Override
    public Collection<News> getAllNews() {
        return newsDao.getAllNews();
    }

    @Override
    public News getNewsById(int id) {
        return newsDao.getNewsById(id);
    }

    @Override
    public News editNews(News news) {
        return newsDao.editNews(news);
    }

    @Override
    public News deleteNews(int id) {
        return newsDao.deleteNews(id);
    }
}
```

And the interface :

```
 package fot.manager.service;

import java.util.Collection;

import fot.manager.model.News;

    public interface NewsService {
        Collection<News> getAllNews();
        News getNewsById(int id);
        News editNews(News news);
        News deleteNews(int id);
    }
```

Dispatcher-servlet :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="bgc.isis.generator.controller"/>

    <context:annotation-config/>

    <!-- Resources -->
    <mvc:resources location="/resources/images/, /resources/css/, /resources/js/" mapping="/resources/**"/>

    <!-- Configures the @Controller programming model -->
    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <!--
    <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/pages/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>-->


    <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass">
            <value>
                org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesView
            </value>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="tilesConfigurer" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesConfigurer">
        <property name="definitions">
            <list>
                <value>/WEB-INF/tiles.xml</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>    
</beans>

<!-- ViewResolver class : org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver -->
```

Thanks a lot to solve my problem :)

Comment: where is your mvc aonnation config ? How are the controlelrs being found/instantiated.

Comment: Humor me for a second and please try changing component-scan to `fot.manager.service.impl` instead of `fot.manager.service`. I know that when you specify a single parent (no commas in the string) Spring will scan all the child packages, but I could not figure out from the documentation if the same applies when you have multiple packages

Comment: Forgot my dispatcher-servlet, sorry... I've added him

Comment: @geoand, I've change the component-scan but the result is the same

Comment: @Odawin would it be possible to upload your code somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this syntax is valid (at least I can't find it in the doc):

```
<context:component-scan base-package="fot.manager.service, fot.manager.dao" />
```

I think you're looking for:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="fot.manager">
    <context:include-filter type="regex" expression=".*\.service\..*"/>
    <context:include-filter type="regex" expression=".*\.dao\..*"/>
</contextn:component-scan>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you've qualified `NewsServiceImpl` Service annotation with the `newsService` logical name, you need to match this with the corresponding [`Qualifier`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.5.6/api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Qualifier.html) annotation otherwise Spring will attempt to inject an unqualified `NewsService` which doesnt exist.

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("newsService")
private NewsService newsService;
```

Alternatively you could simply remove the logical name `NewsServiceImpl's` `@Service` annotation